# Logging Errors in Windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, error-handling, error-logging

I have an windows forms NET application that has intermittent behavior on a machine that is not my development machine.  I need to log some of the internal vars at various stages of execution to see where things are going wrong.  (also I think it is a good idea to log other behavior[s] so if there are bugs missed in testing  can have some idea what is going on in the field)  I found some add on stuff that does this but not only does it seem like over kill, I think I would want to use what is built in to the NET framework instead.  From what I have read this means using trace??   All the examples to create log files using trace(that I can find) are for console applications.  Does anyone have a windows forms example of creating a log file and writing/recording the state of vars during execution to the log file?  I did find an example that logs to the system log but that seems like a bad idea to me even for a beta release.  If I get a log file from a user having difficulty I only want to look at my stuff instead of every thing on that machine plus from a system admin point of view I wouldn't want an application cluttering up the system log in my mind that is for the operating system not a place for applications to take a dump.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've already stated that you'd like something built into the framework, this probably isn't what you want to hear, but I have found log4net works very well. I wouldn't be surprised if it is one of the "overkill" frameworks you've looked at. Another option, and one that is more Microsoft sanctioned, is the Microsoft Enterprise Library -- you would be interested in the Logging framework. (Information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953185%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx), download link [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=bcb166f7-dd16-448b-a152-9845760d9b4c&displaylang=en).)

Comment: I found an example here  http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/how-to-create-log-file-in-c-net-windows-application-t1088.html that just opens a fil in the application directory.

Comment: I implemented it like this namespace MY_Logger { public class Logger { public static string ts = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); public static string appdata_folder = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.ToString(); public static StreamWriter logfile = File.AppendText(String.Format(@"{0}\Sample_Log_{1}.log", appdata_folder, ts)); public Logger() { logfile.WriteLine("User successfully Logged In."); } } }

Comment: I use it like this Logger.logfile.WriteLine("Just got serial port names"); Logger.logfile.WriteLine(myPortNames[i - 1]);  Logger.logfile.WriteLine("After the sort");    Logger.logfile.WriteLine(myPortNames[i - 1]);

Comment: That certainly works. Make sure your logging code doesn't introduce new exceptions. For example, make sure you handle exceptions caused by not having permission to open the file, etc.